# how to handle query string parameter in asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api

here is how I have routing setup.

```
 routes.MapHttpRoute(
                        name: "Authors",
                        routeTemplate: "api/authors",
                        defaults: new { controller = "authors" }
                    );
```

controller action method

```
// GET /api/authors/
    public string GetAuthors(string author_ids)
    {
        return data;
    }
```

Url http://site.com/api/authors?author_ids=1 actually calls controller action but when I don't pass querystring parameter, it says no controller action matching found.

How to handle optional querystring parameter when defining route?

Answer (score 0):

```
// GET /api/authors/
    public IEnumerable<string> GetAuthors()
    {
        return data;
    }
```

You will need to define an action that takes no parameters.

It would be better, however, to add id to your route as optional:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
                        name: "Authors",
                        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can be specific like:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Authors",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

and Action can be:

```
// GET /api/authors/?XXXX
public IEnumerable<string> GetAuthors( [FromUri] String author_ids)
{
    return data;
}
```

This will only match *query string* . **[FromUri]** lets the parameter to be taken from query string.

Answer (score 0):

You may specific like:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Authors",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{author_ids}",
    defaults: new { author_ids = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```